# Reset state to initial state only for specific state variables

Tags: reactjs

I want to reset **state's variable** to initial only for specific value

I have tried this:

```
  const initialState={
     name:'',
     location:'',
     ....
     ....
     ....
   }

   this.state={
     ...initialState,
     spinner:false,
     open:false,
     errorMessage:''
   }

   resetToInitialState = () =>{
   this.setState(...initialState);
   }
```

I am calling this resetToInitialState inside a function like `this.resetToInitialState();`

```
<TextField
                      id="outlined-name"
                      label="Machine id"
                      className={classes.textField}
                      InputProps={{
                        classes: {
                          input: classes.text,
                        },
                      }}
                      value={ !name && null } //tried this not working
                      onChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                    />
```

Comment: What is going wrong? `this.resetToInitialState()` is not reseting to the initial state? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Vencovsky no errors cab please check this in your code to initialize some state values to intial state

Comment: What isn't working for you? So, you get no error but what is happening? What do you expect to see and what do you see? Please add the full code as @Vencovsky requested.

Comment: @devserkan I have added some code now....the problem is the filled value in box is still there.....what I want is to remove the this filled value in a textbox

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `{}`

```
this.setState({...initialState})
```

Comment: @Omkar666 can you please add the full component to your question?

Comment: It's working but I am not able to change the filled value in the textfield but in select it's working for me. I have added some code above please take a look

Comment: I tried in stackblitz and [it's working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1oerrp?file=index.js)

Comment: @Gaspar but the filled boxes will not be reset it's like I want to do something similar to this `document.getElementById('idValue').value=null`

Comment: @Omkar666 but it's [still working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r9vcrm?file=index.js)

Comment: @Gaspar have you even tested it? it's non editable also if I make the state null it doesn't work or make the state to some initial state still it doesn't work and reset it when calling the reset

Comment: @Omkar666 please add the FULL code you are currently working one, because it's getting very confusing and we have very little detail of how your components work.

Comment: did you click the link? O.o the link is the test, please do what @Vencovsky said for a better help

Answer (score 1):

When you try to reset state, you need to clone initial state. If you pass in a reference to `initialState`, that will get mutated when you change state.

```
this.setState({...initialState});
```

To create a controlled component, `TextField` needs the value to be `this.state.name`.

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-name"
  label="Machine id"
  className={classes.textField}
  InputProps={{
    classes: {
      input: classes.text,
    },
  }}
  value={ this.state.name }
  onChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

Edit: Reset `TextField` component when value is My Value

If you only want to reset the state when name is a specific value, you need to create a different `onChange` function and set `onChangeReset` to the `onChange` prop in the `TextField` component.

```
onChangeReset = e => {
  if(e.target.value === 'My Value') {
    this.resetToInitialState();
  else {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value});
  }
}

<TextField
  onChange={this.onChangeReset}
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```

Edit: Add multiple `TextField` components with reset function to reset all of the `TextField` components at the same time.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyGroupedTextFields implemements Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       fields: {},
       spinner: false,
       open: false,
       errorMessage: ''
    };
  }

  resetTextFields = () => {
    const state = { ...this.state };
    state.fields = {};
    this.setState({ state });
  }

  onTextFieldChange = event => {
    const fields = {...this.state.fields};
    fields[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
  }

  submit = async () => {
    // perform submit network request
    // pseudo code
    const response = await submitForm(this.state.fields);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          name='textField1'
          onChange={this.onTextFieldChange}
          value={this.state.fields.textField1}
        />
        <TextField
          name='textField2'
          onChange={this.onTextFieldChange}
          value={this.state.fields.textField2}
        />
        <TextField
          name='textField3'
          onChange={this.onTextFieldChange}
          value={this.state.fields.textField3}
        />
        <button onClick={this.resetTextFields}>
          Reset
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.submit}>
          Submit
        </button
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so let me put this way, I have 20 Textfield inside my component so you are saying I create for all those 20 fields a method called onChangeReset but I guess run out of name since all method name has to be different right? though wrong implementation please post the generic answer which could work in every situation

Comment: So you need 20 Textfield components with a different name variable stored in each one and you want to be able to clear it all at once? Is that correct? I can update the answer with a generic `onChangeReset` for all two text fields. When do you want to reset them all?

Comment: Yes I have some values in state like message, error which I don't want to reset rest I want to reset which I am able to reset(because I am checking for null values in these boxes and it shows the null values when I take the values again but the value is still filled in the boxes).

What I want is simple when I hit a button I want to make all text inside these Textfields to be removed as simple as that

Comment: @Omkar666 I edited my answer to hopefully provide you with the solution

Comment: Okay, the code in onTextFieldChange function will work if in fields we have data as json array....are you setting the value correctly? `fields[event.target.name] = event.target.value;` Are you sure it is a generic answer?

Comment: It's actually not an array, but an object. The bracket notation is one way to access a javascript object when the key is a variable. The the case above, the key is `event.target.name` and so by doing `fields[event.target.name]` we can set the key `event.target.name` to the value `event.target.value`. [More info](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)